# Trying to use matchesKeyinQuery on a relation

Tags: parse-platform

So I'm trying to run a query on a parse.relation that filters the items in the user's relation down to only those that match a query on the object the relation links to. Let's say I have users set up to have an "attending" relation with an object called "meeting." Here's what I have so far

```
    var meetingQuery = new Parse.Query("Meeting");
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    meetingQuery.equalTo("type", "client"); //filter the meetings down to only client meetings
    meetingQuery.find().then(function(theseMeetings){ //I'm pretty sure this .find() isn't needed at all, just doing it to compare the lists of object logged
        _.each(theseMeetings, function(aMeeting) {
            console.log("meetingQuery logging: " + aMeeting.id )
        })
    })

    function testCallback(result){
        var attending = result.relation("attending");
        attending.query().matchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", meetingQuery); //this should take the list of meetings user "George" is attending and filter down to those that have an objectId matching on of the meetings in the meetingsQuery results
        attending.query().find({
          success: function(list) {
            _.each(list, function(listItem) {
                console.log("testCallback logging: " + listItem.id)
            })
          }
        })
    }

    userQuery.equalTo("username", "George");
    userQuery.first().then(testCallback);
```

However, when I run this code, testCallback is logging meeting ids that aren't contained in the results of the meeting query so it doesn't seem like the matchesKeyinQuery is getting applied correctly. Has anyone else had a similar scenario. I can't find an elegant way of querying for parse.relations "backwards" like this.

If anyone doesn't know the solution to this but could just help me with querying for a list of users who have a relation to a particular meeting, that would help as well. Basically this would return the opposite of attending.query() by giving me a list of users attending a given meeting, instead of the list of meetings being attended by a given user.

Turns out querying for relations like this is as easy as querying the user class where the relation column is equal to a given object of the class it targets. This code is explained in the second bit of code in the answer to this thread:

https://www.parse.com/questions/inverse-relationship-support

Comment: [The definition](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_matchesKeyInQuery) states "Adds a constraint that requires that a key's value matches a value in **an object** returned by a different Parse.Query", so it seems like this should not work from what's returned (an array of objects) by `meetingQuery`.

Comment: Actually, under the parameters of that method, it states "The key in the **objects** returned by the query to match against" for the description for the "`queryKey`". This seems conflicting... maybe this is a bug?

Comment: It seems as though this is documented here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/674301645986949/.
Doesn't address the conflicting definition in the doc though...